# how to goto mapfragment after firebase login in kotlin

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am following this google exmple for firebase login
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-kotlin-login/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/firebaseui_login_sample/MainFragment.kt

and my mapstracking example has this

'''
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private lateinit var map: GoogleMap

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    setupLocClient()

}
```

'''
How can I goto the mapsactivity after firebase login success.can you Please let me know,

Comment: I think this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebase/auth) can help.

Comment: You should add a listener on the firebase login and do the routing to your mapfragment  there. Something like:  firebaseAuth!!.addAuthStateListener(this.firebaseAuthListener!!)